# How to show partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a page with information, i want to add there a list (in a form of table) within a partial view. User has to have an ability to sort it by switching radio box.

My problem: the code works fine (i have tried in a separate view), but when i try to switch radio button (they submit page on change and activate 2nd method, which create new model according to radio button) i get html code only from my partial view.

In other words:
i want to : HTML from `view1` + HTML from `myPartial`
i get: only HTML from `myPartial`
I suppose problem is here (calling my `myPartial`):

```
@Html.Action("_ShowEmployeeProjects", "Employee")
```

But when i try to use this:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial/_ShowEmployeeProjects")
```

I get this:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'BTGHRM.Models.EmployeeJobDataViewModel', but this dictionary requires
>   a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BTGHRM.Models.EmployeeProjectHistoryModel]'.

My controllers code:

```
    public PartialViewResult _ShowEmployeeProjects() 
    {
        int EmpId = HRMSession.SelectedEmployeeId;

        using (var db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            List<EmployeeProjectHistoryModel> list = (from t1 in db.ProjectWorkers
                                                      join t2 in db.Projects
                                                      on t1.ProjectId equals t2.ProjectId
                                                      where (t1.WorkerId == EmpId && t1.IsActive == true)
                                                      select new EmployeeProjectHistoryModel()
                                                      {
                                                          ProjectName = t2.ProjectName,
                                                          Activity = t1.Activity,
                                                          StartDate = t1.StartDate,
                                                          EndDate = t1.EndDate
                                                      }).ToList();
            return PartialView("Partial/_ShowEmployeeProjects",list);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult _ShowEmployeeProjects(string ActiveOnlySelect)
    {
        int EmpId = HRMSession.SelectedEmployeeId;
        List<EmployeeProjectHistoryModel> list;
        using (var db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            if (ActiveOnlySelect.Equals("both"))
            {
                list = (from t1 in db.ProjectWorkers
                        join t2 in db.Projects
                        on t1.ProjectId equals t2.ProjectId
                        where (t1.WorkerId == EmpId)
                        select new EmployeeProjectHistoryModel()
                        {
                            ProjectName = t2.ProjectName,
                            Activity = t1.Activity,
                            StartDate = t1.StartDate,
                            EndDate = t1.EndDate
                        }).ToList();
                list.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate);
            }
            else
            {
                list = (from t1 in db.ProjectWorkers
                        join t2 in db.Projects
                        on t1.ProjectId equals t2.ProjectId
                        where (t1.WorkerId == EmpId && t1.IsActive == true)
                        select new EmployeeProjectHistoryModel()
                        {
                            ProjectName = t2.ProjectName,
                            Activity = t1.Activity,
                            StartDate = t1.StartDate,
                            EndDate = t1.EndDate
                        }).ToList();
                list.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate);
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Partial/_ShowEmployeeProjects", list);
    }
```

My partial:

```
@model    List<BTGHRM.Models.EmployeeProjectHistoryModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("_ShowEmployeeProjects", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { type = "main" }))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("ActiveOnlySelect", "activeonly", true, new { id = "ActiveOnlySelect0", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            <label for="ActiveOnlySelect0">@Resources.Localization.show_only_actual</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("ActiveOnlySelect", "both", new { id = "ActiveOnlySelect1", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            <label for="ActiveOnlySelect1">@Resources.Localization.show_all_data</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 15);
if (Model.Any())
{

    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table",
    headerStyle: "table_HeaderStyle",
    footerStyle: "table_PagerStyle",
    rowStyle: "table_RowStyle",
    alternatingRowStyle: "table_AlternatingRowStyle",
    selectedRowStyle: "table_SelectedRowStyle",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ProjectName", Resources.Localization.project, style: "p30"),
        grid.Column("Activity", Resources.Localization.activity, style: "p30"),
        grid.Column("StartDate", Resources.Localization.start_date, format: @<text>
            @if (item.StartDate != null)
            {
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="StartDateLabel">@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</label></span>
                @Html.Hidden("Model.StartDate", (object)item.StartDate.ToShortDateString())
            }
            else
            {
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
            }</text>, style: "p10"),
        grid.Column("EndDate", Resources.Localization.end_date, format: @<text>
            @if (item.EndDate != null)
            {
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="EndDateLabel">@item.EndDate.ToShortDateString()</label></span>
                @Html.Hidden("Model.EndDate", (object)item.EndDate.ToShortDateString())
            }
            else
            {
                <span> &nbsp; </span>
            }</text>, style: "p10")
    )
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for a messy explanation.

Comment: Add your partial view code, may be you're passing model there instead of list

Comment: @Div In that case it wouldn't work in a separate view, but okey - posted)

Comment: Could you tell what stuff will `Html.BeginForm` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a wrong model to your partial. The structure will be:

In your principal Layout:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List[BTGHRM.Models.your_model]
<!-- DO YOUR HTML´S STUFF. You can access to your_model.employee´s list -->
@Html.Partial("Partial/_ShowEmployeeProjects", Model.projects)
```

In your Partial, remember to get the model which you are passing from your main layout:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List[BTGHRM.Models.your_model.projects]
<!-- DO YOUR HTML´S STUFF -->
```

Then, in your controller, you must return return:

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult _ShowEmployeeProjects(string ActiveOnlySelect)
    {
        // DO YOUR MAGIC   
        // model should be a List[BTGHRM.Models.your_model]
        PartialView("Partial/_ShowEmployeeProjects", model);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class your_model
{
   List<Employee> employees;
   List<Project> projects;
.....
}
```

Comment: Problem is that principal view has to show information about employee. Partial - about projects he is currently working on, so they have to use different models.

Comment: You can pass, as a model, a list of object compose with two attributes, your list of employees and your list of projects. I´ll edit my question for giving you the idea...

Comment: IDK, i have to rewrite a lot of code this way, i ll wait a bit, mb someone knows different solutions (btw i can just move my code out of partial view - which is not good practice i know - but all this page looks strange)

Comment: Bbbuuffff, I don´t know if you can do it in a simplest way. Will be interesting if someone knows... Good luck mate! :)

Comment: My mate said that async ajax request will help updating partial view, gona try this and close this question ty)

Comment: It is a different thing. You should use Ajax for refreshing data coming from controller without get all data (just the part you want to refresh avoiding to refresh all page). But if you try this way you should do more changes. A Jquery function (for the request, and probably another jquery function for the other parts), and modify Partial and Main layout controllers. For me, at least, the proper way is which one I told you. Ajax is used for other purpouses. If you want, you can open another question and I will code this way as well... ;)